# Adding metadata to PDF via PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, metadata, pdftk

I need to augment a PDF with a custom metadata field on download in PHP (5.3).

I have been looking at the [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) library, but I can't get my head around how I would get PHP to interface with it on our (Ubuntu) web server.

The deprecated PDFInfo library seems like a dead end.

Is there a simpler/easier/better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html). It's from the Zend Framework but can be used as a standalone component. Adding metadata is as easy as:

```
  $pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($pdfPath);
  $pdf->properties['Title'] = 'New Title.';
  $pdf->save($pdfPath);
```