# Edit metadata of PDF in Ruby created with minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, minimagick

I need to edit metadata of PDF file created with minimagick, to be specific, title of pdf. I can set filename, no problem, but I haven't found any solution how to change that title. For example it apears in chrome pdf title thing when PDF is open.

This is snippet of my code:

```
pdf = MiniMagick::Image.open(template_image_path)

pdf.combine_options do |c|
  calibrate_name_text(c, name)
end
result.format 'pdf'

File.open(result.path, 'r') do |f|
  send_data f.read, type: 'application/pdf', filename: 'pdf_file.pdf'
end
```

This is title, even when pdf name if for example 'pdf_file':
[image: wrong title]

When I use send_file function like this I got error in console:

```
send_file result.path, type: 'application/pdf', filename: 'pdf_file.pdf', url_based_filename: false
```

composite: gAMA: CRC error `' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1746.

And pdf file has status 'Failed - Network error'

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `file_name(name)` is?

Comment: Alternatively, you can try using `send_file` and set the `url_based_filename` option to `false` - https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file

Comment: @Vidur I have edited my question, it was my function for stripping stuff

Comment: It seems not possible with ImageMagick in the first place; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921618/set-a-document-name-when-creating-a-pdf-from-an-image