# set meta tags in existing pdf

Tags: php, pdf

I'm trying to set the meta tags of a existing pdf generated by another software.

I've a my linux server and I've installed PDFlib (http://php.net/pdf) but I still have not been able.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I had already read that post, but I would avoid using Zend

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to the question [Adding metadata to PDF via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3060078/3658574).

The correct answer from [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon):

> You could use [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.info.html). It's from the Zend Framework but can be used as a standalone component. Adding metadata is as easy as:
>
> ```
> $pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($pdfPath);
> $pdf->properties['Title'] = 'New Title.';
> $pdf->save($pdfPath);
> ```

Comment: I had already read that post, but I would avoid using Zend