# Change just metadata from a pdf document with mpdf

Tags: php, metadata, mpdf

I'm trying to change the metadata of a document previously generated with another library (wkhtmltopdf) but when I create a mpdf objet change the data and save with the same name I'm just overwriting the previous pdf file for this empty new one. (with the proper metadata but empty)

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => '/var/www/storage/temp']);
$mpdf->SetTitle('title');
$mpdf->SetAuthor('email');
$mpdf->SetKeywords('id');
$mpdf->Output('/var/www/storage/app/myfile.pdf');
```

With mpdf can I open previous document change the metadata and save the same document? (wkhtmltopdf can't handle metadata, just title)

Comment: There is a way to import pages from another document but when I call SetImportUse() php says that is a "undefined method"

Comment: mPDF is a PDF generator, not an editor. It seems to have [limited support from importing](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/importing-files-templates.html) but you aren't even trying to use it.

Comment: I'm trying and it's working but it's messy (margins look weird because I'm importing one page inside of another). Any other idea how to edit the metadata of a pdf file with php?

Answer (score -1):

mPDF is designed for creating new PDF files, not for changing/modifying/updating existing PDF files.

PHP solution:

- Zend_Pdf as described [here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.info.html). (See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3060106/20996936).)

External Toolkits:

- regular PDF metadata: PDFtk, [operation `update_info_utf8`](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-update-info-utf8)
- XMP PDF metadata: exiftool, [option -tagsFromFile](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html)

Note that some PDF metadata is duplicated and exists in both the regular PDF metadata and the XMP PDF metadata:

> Since PDF v 1.6 metadata can be stored in the special XML document
> attached to the PDF (XMP - » Extensible Metadata Platform).
>
> This XML document can be retrieved and attached to the PDF with
> `Zend_Pdf::getMetadata()` and `Zend_Pdf::setMetadata($metadata)` methods:
>
> [...]
>
> Common document properties are duplicated in the Info structure and
> Metadata document (if presented). It's user application responsibility
> now to keep them synchronized.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.info.html

Answer (score -1):

You can do that if you modify the code a bit.
Here is how to do that.

First locate `/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php`

Add these 2 methods

```
var $creationDate;
var $modifieDate;

function SetCreation($date)
    {
        // Creation Date
        $this->creationDate = strtotime($date);
    }

    function SetModified($date)
    {
        // Modifie Date
        $this->modifieDate = strtotime($date);
    }
```

Then in the same file search for `writeInfo`

Previously it will be like `$this->metadataWriter->writeInfo()`
Now change it to below and save

```
$this->metadataWriter->writeInfo($this->creationDate, $this->modifieDate);
```

Now locate this file `/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Writer/MetadataWriter.php`
And search for `writeInfo`

Add optional parameter to `public function writeInfo()`

```
public function writeInfo($creation = null, $modified = null)
```

Then Replace in the same function

```
$now = PdfDate::format(time());
$this->writer->write('/CreationDate ' . $this->writer->string('D:' . $now));
$this->writer->write('/ModDate ' . $this->writer->string('D:' . $now));
```

To

```
$now = PdfDate::format($modified??time());
$before = PdfDate::format($creation??time());
$this->writer->write('/CreationDate ' . $this->writer->string('D:' . $before));
$this->writer->write('/ModDate ' . $this->writer->string('D:' . $now));
```

Done, now you can set modified and creation dates like

```
$mpdf->SetCreation('2023-01-09 11:17AM');
$mpdf->SetModified('2023-01-09 11:17PM');
```